# NSDate countdown in days

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I want to create a countdown of the number of days until a date.  I'm not interested in hours or minutes, just the number of days from the current date until the set date.  This is what I have been trying:

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [date description];
// this **dateString** string will have **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0530"**
//  NSMutableString *mutString = dateString;
NSArray *arr = [dateString componentSeperatedByString:@" "];
// arr will have [0] -> yyyy-MM-dd, [1] -> HH:mm:ss, [2] -> +0530 (time zone)
```

But it doesn't work because the current date is giving time in minutes and seconds.

```
//NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *start = [arr objectAtIndex:0];//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentDate];//@"2011-11-05";
NSLog(@"%@",start);
NSString *end = @"2011-6-03";

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];
[f release];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                    fromDate:startDate
                                                      toDate:endDate
                                                     options:0];
NSInteger days = [components day];
[gregorianCalendar release];
NSLog(@"%i", days);
```

I don't really understand much of this code, I'm not familar with NSDate and formatter, but this is my combination of a bunch of internet code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can count the number of days from current day by this way....

NSDate NewDate = Here Comes your compare date;

NSDateComponents *dateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

```
NSCalendar *Calander = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSDateComponents *comps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

dateComp = [Calander components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
[comps setDay:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM"];
[comps setMonth:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
[comps setYear:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
[comps setHour:05];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm"];
[comps setMinute:30];

NSDate *currentDate=[Calander dateFromComponents:comps];

//NSLog(@"Current Date is :- '%@'",currentDate);

dateComp = [Calander components:unitFlags fromDate:newDate];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    [comps setDay:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate] intValue]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    [comps setMonth:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate] intValue]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
    [comps setYear:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate] intValue]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    [comps setHour:05];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm"];
    [comps setMinute:30];

    NSDate *reminderDate=[Calander dateFromComponents:comps];

    //NSLog(@"Current Date is :- '%@'",reminderDate);

    //NSLog(@"Current Date is :- '%@'",currentDate);

    NSTimeInterval ti = [reminderDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];

    //NSLog(@"Time Interval is :- '%f'",ti);
    int days = ti/86400;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSDateComponents` to trim off the time:

```
NSDate* targetDate = ...
NSDate* today = [NSDate date]

NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]

unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
targetDate = [cal dateFromComponents:[cal components:unitFlags fromDate:targetDate]];
today = [cal dateFromComponents:[cal components:unitFlags fromDate:today]];
```

And then grab the differences in days by specifying only the `day` date unit (this might work without the code above, I'm not sure):

```
int days = [[cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today  toDate:targetDate  options:0] day];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code,

```
NSTimeInterval dateDiff = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
int countDown=trunc(dateDiff/(60*60*24));
```